# Iterate over an array of selected jQuery Objects?

Tags: jquery

How do you iterate through a group of selected jQuery objects so that you can perform jQuery functions on each object individually?

```
   
 <div class="foobar">abc</div>
 <div class="foobar">123</div>
 <div class="foobar">abc123</div>
```

I can select the group:

```
var foobarObjects = jQuery('.foobar')
```

But how would you go through each jQuery object in foobarObject and manipulate each one individually? I thought I could use `jQuery().each` but that only allows me to work with DOM objects, not jQuery objects. I also tried a for loop in conjunction with the `jQuery().eq(i)` function, but that seems to merge the items together.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `$(this)`

```
$('.foobar').each(function(){
  $(this).blah//refers to jquery object.
});
```

Comment: B.T.W. if you need to set something like attribute or class on ALL items in group you can simply use $('.foobar').attr("blah", "blah");

Comment: Hey Stefan, how would you also retrieve the index of the element? Usually, I would use the callbacks, i and v, to get the index and value separately. Is there any way to do this with "this"?

Comment: @ArtemYevtushenko http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/ the first argument is the index, second is the value

Comment: @StefanKendall yes, but I’m curious to know if there’s a way of using “this” and if there are any benefits. Practically having both callbacks isn’t an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Within `jQuery().each()` you can use `$(this)` to use the jQuery functions on the current DOM object.